# Problems with SQL query finding three names with the most records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table and I want to display the 3 names (Ted, Ringo, Paul) that have the most records using an SQL query.
It's a primitive question, but please help me.

my table:

[image]

Comment: You really could have simply posted the table as text. An image isn't making anything helpful.

Comment: Can you explain the _criteria_ by which these names should be selected?

Comment: @Lion - You have edit privileges, you know?

Comment: I've fixed it for you, @Lion, so we can all delete the discussion.

Comment: What does the number in the `text` column mean? Is it important when you calculate the number of records?

Comment: 2 Oded
I want display 3 names that has most records in table, but value of fields 'text' must be ignore

Comment: 2 Mikael Eriksson: no its just some symbols, they doesn't meaning

Comment: Just curious, what would happen with ties?  so if 5 people all had 10 records and 10 was the max should all 5 show or just 3 of the 5?  or if 2 people had 10 records and 2 had 9 and the rest are less than that should the 1st two show and just 1 of the 9? or what?

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT TOP 3 Name
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Comment: "I want display 3 names(Ted,Ringo,Paul) that have the most records"...   The rest of the question is ambiguous, but I think that part is clear... unless he means record as in "album" as opposed to record as in "row"...

Comment: Thanx, its working
how to implement it in LINQ-Query?

Comment: @user: You could post a new question for that. If you do, please search the site first, maybe there's an answer already.